# Discord bot only connects to voice channel that the user was in when the bot runs

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to create a code that requires my bot to identify the current voice channel the user is in and retrieve what users are in that channel. However the bot will only identify a voice channel that the user was in when i run the script. It will also return the same voice channel even if the user has left. And if i run the script before i join the voice channel it will say the user is not in a channel at all. Why does my code sometimes recognise a user is in a voice channel and sometimes not?
This is the current code im using for testing:

```
@bot.command()
async def check(ctx):
  
   channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
   members = channel.voice_states
   print(members)
```

I'm running the script off Replit (something tells me this could be my the hosting source or something i don't know this has caused me too many headaches).

I tried to make my explanation better but if its still bad please tell me ill go fetch a friend who can help me fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have the right idea retrieving the channel. but you also want to check to make sure the user invoking the command is actually in a voice channel.

```
@bot.command()
async def check(ctx):
  
   channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
   if channel is None:
     return await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")

   else:
     memList = []
     for member in channel.members:
          memList.append(member.name)
```

Now you have a list of members connected to that voice channel.